# Odoo: how to set default field for many2many field by id?

Tags: odoo, odoo-15

i want to set default value in many2many field for example:
[image: field view]

that field in models.py:

```
# alarms
alarm_ids = fields.Many2many(
    'calendar.alarm', 'calendar_alarm_calendar_event_rel',
    string='Reminders', ondelete="restrict",
    help="Notifications sent to all attendees to remind of the meeting.")
```

also it is default values created by system, and i want first variant by default:
[image: existed records with id`s]

i know that i can set it by id, but dont know how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Command](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/fr/developer/reference/backend/orm.html#odoo.fields.Command) to set `X2many` field values.

From the documentation:

> Via Python, we encourage developers craft new commands via the various functions of this namespace. We also encourage developers to use the command identifier constant names when comparing the 1st element of existing commands.

***Example:***

```py
from odoo import Command, models, fields

        
class CalendarEvent(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'calendar.event'
    
    alarm_ids = fields.Many2many(default=lambda self: [Command.link(self.env.ref('calendar.alarm_notif_1').id)])
```

Answer (score 0):

i just watch in postgres, there is no id`s like in xml screenshots, i just take id of a record and find some documentation.
next example works:
[image]

Comment: Why is there no ID like in the XML?

Comment: this example doesn't work with text id's. It works with number id's, placed in postgres database record. 
example: default=[4, <id_of_record>]

Comment: Look into the other answer and you will see the solution with an xml id (so called external ID). (`self.env.ref('calendar.alarm_notif_1').id`)